# Temporary table in click house

Tags: datatable, clickhouse

I have several subqueries and i want insert my output to a temp table.
In SQL server I wrote :

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ( SELECT cl1, cl2, cl3, ... FROM TABLE1 WHERE cl1=A)
```

but it does not work in click house.
I don't know what is Engine in click house.

Comment: What's the client interface you use to run this statement?

Answer (score 0):

try

```sql
insert into dest select ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, no need to specify a table engine:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE <NAME> AS 
SELECT ....
```